# Jsoup после создания .jar не работает

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

До создания .jar в idea всё работало хорошо, и продолжает работать в оболочке, но в jar выходит ошибка:

```
org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=403, URL=[https://www.avito.ru/kazan/tovary_dlya_kompyutera/komplektuyuschie/videokarty-ASgBAgICAkTGB~pm7gmmZw?f=ASgBAQICAkTGB~pm7gmmZwFA~LwNFJjSNA&s=104&user=1]
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:890)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:829)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:366)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:353)
        at org.jsoup.Jsoup.parse(Jsoup.java:246)
        at Parser.main(Parser.java:16)
        at Main.lambda$main$0(Main.java:24)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Парсю так:

```
 String url = "https://www.avito.ru/kazan/tovary_dlya_kompyutera/komplektuyuschie/videokarty-ASgBAgICAkTGB~pm7gmmZw?f=ASgBAQICAkTGB~pm7gmmZwFA~LwNFJjSNA&s=104&user=1";
 Document page = Jsoup.parse(new URL(url), 999999999);
```

Запускаю скрипт в потоке:

```
 new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                while (true){
                    Parser.main(args);
                    Thread.sleep(3600000);
                }
            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).start();
```

Comment: насколько понимаю, статус `403`, означает `допарсился` или если быть тактичнее: `в доступе отказано`

Comment: но в оболочке работает